# База данных вместе с libgdx

Tags: база-данных, libgdx

Какую базу данных можно использовать вместе с libgdx под андроид.

Comment: На клиенте SQLite, на сервере любую.

Comment: SQLite с libgdx не работает

Comment: https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite